# Chrome developer tools isn't showing my browser resolution when I resize it

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Whenever I resize my window it doesn't show me the resolution in the top right anymore? Does anyone know why? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to a post on Google Chrome Developer Tools group (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/fbueXIfX09k) it was unintentional and has been fixed in Chrome Canary.